# Find column index of minimum value from 2D arrays

Tags: arrays, matlab, indexing

Suppose I have a 2D array like this :

```
Array = [1 2 3; 5 1 6; 4 3 2]
```

I want to find the minimum value between each row, and
save the column index of that result. 
I want my answer's like this :

```
ans = [1; 1; 2]
```

and the index :

```
column_index = [1; 2; 3]
```

Can somebody please help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking to find the minimum values along the second dimension. Use [**`min`**](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/min.html) -

```
[minval,column_index] = min(Array,[],2)
```